# Response body from fetch not successfully parsing to JSON, even though it's verifiably valid JSON

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch some data from a webservice like so:

```
async function request(path: string, args: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<Response> {
    const headers: RequestInit = {
        mode: "no-cors" as RequestMode,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const url = `${ROOT_URL}/${path}?apiKey=${API_KEY}`
    const options = {
        ...args,
        ...headers,
    }

    const result = await fetch(url, options)
    return result;
}

try {

    const response = await request('my/endpoint', {
        method: 'GET',
    })

    console.log('received response: ')
    console.log(response)

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result)
    return Promise.resolve(result)

} catch(error) {

    console.log('error:')
    console.log(error)
    return Promise.reject(error)

}
```

When sending this request, I see the following error in the console:

> [Log] SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern. — imagesSlice.ts:110 (bundle.js, line 633)

Additionally, the `body` field of the response object is null.

However, if I `curl` the exact URL, or paste it into the browser, the response body contains the correct JSON, which is verifiable by jsonlint.

What could be failing here?  And also how can I debug this?

I have tried using `await response.text()` to take a look at the response body, and this returns an empty string.

Comment: `no-cors` will prevent you from reading a body. `no-cors` is almost never what you want. This issue is so prevalent on stack overflow, I wrote a small article some time ago: https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: Ah this makes sense.  I am only using this as a crutch because cors is not working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75820001/how-do-i-enable-cors-for-an-api-gateway-api-using-cdk

Comment: it doesn't do what you think it does